# Ubuntu Phones for the US

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Will there be Ubuntu Phones for the Ubuntu users of the US? I've seen loads of articles about the Bq Aquaris phone, but, it's only available in Europe, what about us American Ubuntu users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bq will only be sold on the EU. The meizu will be sold in China an the EU. TheY have plans for USA but have not reveal anything about when it will be avalaible. 
Read [this link](https://svij.org/blog/2015/02/13/canonical-ceo-jane-silber-about-ubuntu-phone/).